# Save Image from web service without quality loss

Tags: java, image

So, download method is:

```
   private void imageDownload(String file_path) throws IOException {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
    Response response = call.execute();
    saveImage(response);
   }
```

And save method is:

```
    public void saveImage(Response response) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
        File outputFile = new File("images/"+ new Date() + ".png");
        ImageOutputStream ios = new FileImageOutputStream(outputFile);
        ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png").next();
        ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
        param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        writer.setOutput(ios);            
        writer.write(image);
    }
```

Result is:

Source image looks like [source cat image](https://ibb.co/2qjsyN8)

Image after downloading and saving:

[image: poor pixel cat]

Yeah, it is real size.

Source image is 3872  x  2592 .jpeg

Downloaded image is 90  x  60 .png

What should i do to fix this? I tried different images formats, but it didn't help.

Comment: Note that there are two different URLs. There's `https://i.ibb.co/jhLWTRV/cat1.jpg`, which is the full-size JPG, and `https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAokI.png`, which looks like a PNG thumbnail. You seem to be downloading the thumbnail, though you don't seem to show where the `file_path` is coming from?

Comment: upvoted for cute cat

Comment: thanks a lot! I really downloaded thumbnail instead of image)

Answer (score 1):

The first time I tried to download the image, I got a 162-byte result, but the second time it worked perfectly for me and I got the correct resolution, so maybe try running your code again. Alternatively, you can also just open the image in your browser and press CTRL (or CMD on Mac) + S to save the image. Also, I am not sure why you have such a complicated code to save your image, as `Files.write(Path.of(file), new URL(url).openStream().readAllBytes());` should do the job just fine.